# Excel - I want to create absolute reference that won't change when I insert new column

Tags: excel

What I want to do is:

Let's say the columns are dates, the rows are merchants, the data is volume. New columns are inserted every day for the new date right to left (so the newest date comes left). New rows are also inserted often for new merchants.

I need to calculate the volume for last 1 week. Since we're constantly adding columns, I need the columns in the formula to stay the same. However, since we're adding rows as well, I need the rows in the formula to be able to be dragged down for when we add a new merchant. Absolute reference with $ doesn't work for adding new columns, it still changes the column in my formula. I tried working with INDIRECT() but then the rows won't change when I drag the formula down.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Picture below for example - our formula needs to be in A2 and to be able to be dragged down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the non volatile INDEX:

```
=SUM(INDEX(2:2,3):INDEX(2:2,9))
```

OFFSET and INDIRECT are the other two options but both of them are volatile and will re calculate every time a change is made in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `OFFSET`. So `A2` would be =SUM(OFFSET(A2,0,2,1,7)), summing the 1x7 cells starting 2 columns right of `A2`